# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in service liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

in chrome console when i click on button(delete save) i get this error 
"**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**"
also it print obj on console and appear it's data ({companyId: 49305, groupId: 49343, keywordSearch: "misr1", query: "?searchType=Bib&SearchValueTBX=misr1&SearchTypeDDL…cet_Author=&Facet_CountryName=&Facet_LibraryName=", saved: true, …}
)

```
function userSave(){
var userId=$("#userId").val();
var companyId=$("#companyId").val();
debugger;
Liferay.Service(
          '/MyLibrary_ServiceBuilder-portlet.searchhistory/display-saved',
          {
            userId: userId,
            companyId: companyId
          },
          function(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
            html='';
            var i;
            for(i =0;i<obj.length;i++){

                html+="<li id='"+obj[i].searchHistoryId+"' name='keywordSearch'>"+obj[i].keywordSearch+"</li>";
                html+="<li>"+obj[i].searchTime+"</li>";
                html+="<input type='hidden' id='saved' name='saved' value='"+obj[i].saved+"'>";
                debugger;
                html+="<input type='button' name='updateSearch' onclick='statusUpdate("+obj[i].toString()+");' value='delete save'>";
            }

            $("#userSave").append(html);
          }
        );
}

function statusUpdate(obj){
console.log(obj);
debugger;
obj={
        'userId':userId,
        'companyId':companyId,
        'groupId':groupId,
        'keywordSearch':'"'+keywordSearch+'"',
        'updatedOn':updatedOn,
        'saved':saved,
        'query':'"'+query+'"'
}
Liferay.Service(
          '/MyLibrary_ServiceBuilder-portlet.searchhistory/update-to-search-history',
          {
            strSearchHistory: obj
          },
          function(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
          }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the code `onclick='statusUpdate("+obj[i].toString()+");'`, **obj[i]** is an object and calling **toString ()** returns a string **"[object Object ]"** and not a serialized object.

```
JSON.stringify(testeObj)
```

Or

```
obj={
    'userId':userId,
    'companyId':companyId,
    'groupId':groupId,
    'keywordSearch':'"'+keywordSearch+'"',
    'updatedOn':updatedOn,
    'saved':saved,
    'query':'"'+query+'"'
```

}

The snippet `'userId':userId`, the **userId** variable has not been defined in context.

I hope I have helped.